# what is wrong with this snippet

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php } elseif($_SOMETHING == 1 && $_ANOTHER_THING == 2) { ?>
<?php $_NAME = urlencode($_NAME); ?>
<?php $_MGT_NAME = urlencode($_MGT_NAME); ?>
</div>    
<?php } ?>
```

I am getting this error expected ';'

Comment: man, please, format you code

Comment: Do you get a line and column number with the error?

Comment: Figure out some way to wrap the code so that it is readable. I'm not going to bother with trying to answer this if it is annoying to read.

Comment: Please post complete code. Your snippet looks fine.

Comment: `$_WHY $_ARE $_ALL $_YOUR $_VARIABLES $_NAMED $_LIKE $_SUPERGLOBALS`

Comment: that is how this application was when i first got to it so the superglobal look was not my plan. The error is only happening on IE and it has to be this snippet because when i take it out, no error. The error is expected ';' line 164 char 298

Comment: @John: which line is line 164?

Comment: Keep your PHP, JavaScript and HTML separate FTW.

Comment: it would be helpful to see the html ouput as rendered.

Comment: @john: remember that IE's errors are CLIENT-SIDE errors. The client never sees the raw PHP code. That's line 164 of the generated html/javascript, not line 164 of the .php script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The horror. The horror.

Here's the actual error, in the `onclick` attribute value:

```
lpButtonCTTUrl = 'http:...Ad%20Source=somesite.com& ='+escape(document.location); imageUrl=<?php print "http://{$_SERVER['SITENAME']}/images/";?>&referrer
```

That is, there should be a `+'` instead of `;` after the `document.location` inclusion, and there should be a closing quote after the imageURL inclusion, and `referrer` is in the wrong place (it should be just before the `document.location` inclusion.

It also has problems like the use of `escape` (never use `escape`. For URL-encoding you actually want `encodeURLComponent`); the unescaped ampersands all over the place; and the lack of HTML- and URL-encoding of values output from PHP, potentially causing cross-site scripting risks.

Writing a value inside a URL component inside a URL inside a JavaScript string literal inside an attribute value inside HTML is *utter insanity* so it's no surprise there are mistakes. Let's try to bring some maintainability to this madness. Break out the JavaScript and URL creation into separate steps where getting the escaping right is possible.

```
function urlencodearray($a) {
    $o= array();
    foreach ($a as $k=>$v)
        array_push($o, rawurlencode($k).'='.rawurlencode($v));
    return implode('&', $o);
}
function h($s) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($s);
}
```

With these utility functions defined, then:

```
<?php } elseif($_SOMETHING == 1 && $_ANOTHER_THING == 2) { ?>
    <?php
        $lpbase= 'http://server.iad.liveperson.net/hc/84152841/?';
        $linkurl= $lpbase.urlencodearray(array(
            'cmd'=>'file',
            'file'=>'visitorWantsToChat',
            'site'=>'84152841',
            'byhref'=>'1',
            'skill'=>'somesiteILS',
            'SESSIONVAR!skill'=>'somesiteILS',
            'SESSIONVAR!Management Company'=>$_MGT_NAME,
            'SESSIONVAR!Community'=>$_NAME,
            'SESSIONVAR!Ad%20Source'=>'somesite.com',
            'imageUrl'=>"http://{$_SERVER['SITENAME']}/images/"
        ));
        $imgurl= $lpbase.urlencodearray(array(
            'cmd'=>'repstate',
            'site'=>'84152841',
            'channel'=>'web',
            'ver'=>'1',
            'skill'=>'somesiteILS',
            'imageUrl'=>"http://{$_SERVER['SITENAME']}/images/"
        ));
    ?>

    <div id="caller_tag">
        <a id="_lpChatBtn" target="chat84152841" href="<?php h($url); ?>">
            <img src="<?php h($imgurl); ?>" name="hcIcon" alt="Chat" border="0">
        </a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById('_lpChatBtn').onclick= function() {
                var url= this.href+'&referrer='+encodeURIComponent(location.href);
                if ('lpAppendVisitorCookies' in window)
                    url= lpAppendVisitorCookies(url);
                if ('lpMTag' in window && 'addFirstPartyCookies' in lpMTag)
                    url= lpMTag.addFirstPartyCookies(url)
                window.open(url, this.target, 'width=475,height=400,resizable=yes');
                return false;
            };
        </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

With an unformatted mess like that it's no wonder you can't find the error.

I tried running it through HTML Tidy but it doesn't like anything between the comments.

```
mesite.com& ='+escape(document.location); imageUrl=<?php print "ht
```

I'm not good at reading long lines like that but shouldn't this be

```
mesite.com& ='+escape(document.location) +'imageUrl=<?php print "ht
```

Comment: that fixed the first part not i am getting the same error furthur down the string on char 392

Answer (score 2):

First of: why are you opening and closing PHP so many times, you could write it like:

```
<?php
} elseif($_SOMETHING == 1 && $_ANOTHER_THING == 2) {
$_NAME = urlencode($_NAME);
$_MGT_NAME = urlencode($_MGT_NAME);
?>
<div id="caller_tag">
<!-- BEGIN LivePerson Button Code --><a id="_lpChatBtn"    href='http://server.iad.liveperson.net/hc/84152841/?cmd=file&file=visitorWantsToChat&site=84152841&byhref=1&SESSIONVAR!skill=somesiteILS&SESSIONVAR!Management%20Company=<?php print $_MGT_NAME; ?>&SESSIONVAR!Community=<?php print $_NAME; ?>&SESSIONVAR!Ad%20Source=somesite.com&imageUrl=<?php print "http://{$_SERVER['SITENAME']}/images/";?>' target='chat84152841'  onClick="lpButtonCTTUrl = 'http://server.iad.liveperson.net/hc/84152841/?cmd=file&file=visitorWantsToChat&site=84152841&SESSIONVAR!skill=somesiteILS&SESSIONVAR!Management%20Company=<?php print $_MGT_NAME; ?>&SESSIONVAR!Community=<?php print $_NAME; ?>&SESSIONVAR!Ad%20Source=somesite.com& ='+escape(document.location); imageUrl=<?php print "http://{$_SERVER['SITENAME']}/images/";?>&referrer lpButtonCTTUrl = (typeof(lpAppendVisitorCookies) != 'undefined' ? lpAppendVisitorCookies(lpButtonCTTUrl) : lpButtonCTTUrl); lpButtonCTTUrl = ((typeof(lpMTag)!='undefined' && typeof(lpMTag.addFirstPartyCookies)!='undefined')?lpMTag.addFirstPartyCookies(lpButtonCTTUrl):lpButtonCTTUrl);window.open(lpButtonCTTUrl,'chat84152841','width=475,height=400,resizable=yes');return false;" ><img src='http://server.iad.liveperson.net/hc/84152841/?cmd=repstate&site=84152841&channel=web&&ver=1&imageUrl=<?php print "http://{$_SERVER['SITENAME']}/images/";?>&skill=somesiteILS' name='hcIcon' alt='Chat Button' border=0></a><!-- END LivePerson Button code -->
</div>
```

And also: the error must be somewhere else, I can't see a missing ";" in php in the code you pasted, unless the error is in javascript.